# Can you access the same data on a DXF as on a PDF version of the DXF?

Tags: dxf

I am searching for info regarding the technical limitations of the PDF vis a vis DXF for programming purposes.  I need to know whether there are operations or data embedded within the DXF that cannot be accessed via the PDF standard.  Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is quite a bit of data in a dxf that would not be in a PDF. A basic difference is that PDF is a graphical representation, whereas a DXF can have information about three diminsional aspects.  A DXF may also contain multiple views of the elements it contains, for instance several paper space views at different scales.

However, it is possible that the DXF files your are dealing with may not take full advantage of the DXF capabilities.  Some additional background regarding your situation and what kind of things you want to accomplish would be helpful in narrowing down which differences would be applicable/problematic in your case.

Comment: The DXF in question would be used as part of an electronic permit process (building permits, use permits, construction permits, etc).  Ideally, some types of validations could be performed on the submitted document based on information that can be obtained via the file specification.

Comment: This is helpful information, which you should probably add to the original question.  Can you go into more detail regarding what type of documents (floor plan, blueprints, etc.) and what validations (floor area, dimensioning, particular data or test)?